# Have no choice to duplicate a variable in javascript or else its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, variables

Here you can find my whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/dpbbd/

Everything is working fine, but there is something that tickle me and its this:

```
    function drawLine()
    {
        var div1 = document.getElementById('circle');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('companyName');
        connect(div1, div2, "#000", 1, "line1");
        var div1 = document.getElementById('circle2');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('companyName');
        connect(div1, div2, "#000", 1, "line2");
        var div1 = document.getElementById('circle3');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('companyName');
        connect(div1, div2, "#000", 1, "line3");
        $('.line1').fadeIn(800, function() {
        });
        $('.line2').fadeIn(800, function() {
        });
        $('.line3').fadeIn(800, function() {
        });
    }
```

You see im declaring var div1 div2 over and over even if its the same damn thing... Now i tryed this:

```
function drawLine()
{
    var div1 = document.getElementById('circle');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('companyName');
    connect(div1, div2, "#000", 1, "line1");
    var div3 = document.getElementById('circle2');
     connect(div3, div2, "#000", 1, "line2");
    var div4 = document.getElementById('circle3');
    connect(div4, div2, "#000", 1, "line3");
    $('.line1').fadeIn(800, function() {
    });
    $('.line2').fadeIn(800, function() {
    });
    $('.line3').fadeIn(800, function() {
    });
}
```

The error that give me is the line start drawing from the circle as normal, then go right at 0 like if div2 never existed... The first circle is working fine and the line connect to the text in the middle cause the variable is declared right before it. But as soon as i remove the var div2 before other connect, not working anymore.

Could someone explain to me whats happening o_O

Comment: Can't understand your issue

Comment: Try to copy the code in the jsfiddle at the right place you will see what i mean, the second code would be suposed to work as far as i know.. But its not.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why on Earth do you stick with `document.getElementById`?

Comment: Well i started javascript today... what would be an alternative to getelementbyid? cause if i dont do that in firefox its not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you change the document.body's innerhtml all objects are recreated.
that's why you have to re-get the element all the time.

if you don't want to have to do that you'll need to append to the body instead of changing its html all the time.

Comment: ahhhhh thanks alot now that explain it. :) I was kinda confused!

Comment: @Aenil Seriously, *never ever* do such a thing as `element.innerHTML += ...`. This makes it rebuild the whole content and can be extremely slow. Add content with other methods, like `appendChild` or even `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: Well i have to recalculate the position of the line if the screen is resized or else it stay fixed in the screen and it look very ugly. So removing then recreating is what i need i think, not appending. And yeah i agree with a tons of code it would be very slow but im using a timer which is used .5 second after inactivity (while resizing) then remove/recreate the line again.